# How can we troubleshoot why a 404 page doesn't retain its url rather changes to another 404 page of its own?

Tags: seo, url, 404, technical-seo

I am working on a client website for a technical SEO audit for the first time. They have a 404 page where the URL of the missing page is not retained, instead, it goes to a separate 404 page. For example, let's say as a user, I need to access https://www.example.com/careers , but this page is not there, so the browser redirects me too https://www.example.com/error/error/notfound?http:www.example.com. This page has all the content that a 404 page has, but the URL changes. Ideally, 404 page should not be there, that I understand, but for audit and temporary fix, shouldn't the URL have been https://www.example.com/careers  and that page should show "page not found" info? How can I check, why this is happening. Also, this page is running on a .NET platform.

Comment: Have you checked the IIS logs or are you saying your logs aren't showing the referring page?

Comment: For auditing purposes, I only have access to their GSC :(

Comment: This is likely happening because the 404 page they are going to includes redirect code.  You may be able to use CURL or similar to check the raw response when you make the request.